# Error while trying to deserialize object

Tags: java, jackson

I have this json: `{"backwards":false,"idFrom":-1}`

And a method:

```
private Object[] instantiateFromRequest(Class[] paramTypes) throws IOException {
        Object[] params = new Object[paramTypes.length];
        if (paramTypes.length == 0) {
            return params;
        }

        HttpServletRequest req = RequestSupplier.request();
        InputStream is = req.getInputStream();
        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        if (paramTypes.length == 1) {
            params[0] = m.readValue(is, paramTypes[0]);
        } else {
            String[] vals = m.readValue(is, String[].class);//trouble here
            for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.length; i++) {
                if (paramTypes[i] == String.class) {
                    params[i] = vals[i];
                } else {
                    params[i] = m.readValue(vals[i], paramTypes[i]);
                }

            }
        }
        return params;
    }
```

(`params[0]` is `long` and params `params[1]` is `boolean`)
Which should return the objects in the json. The trouble comes on the marked line. I get an Exception:
`Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of START_OBJECT token`
Which I have no idea why it is happening. Can anybody help me?

EDIT: It actually seems, that I'm trying to get an array, not an object here. Chaning the JSON to :`[-1, false]` solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to serialize through an array of string, where you have another generic type object in your ***`json`***.

***Try the following:***

```
String val = m.readValue(is, String.class);
```

***OR:***

```
ContentBean myContentBean = m.readValue(is, ContentBean.class);
```

Where `ContentBean`  has two properties:

1. ***`backwards`***
2. ***`idFrom`***

With their getters and setters.

And it should work perfectly.

**EDIT:**

Are you sure about:

***`params[1] is long and params params[0] is boolean`***

Cause it seems the reverse to me . . .

Comment: yep, it's reverse, sorry about that

Comment: aaand, nope, I still get the exception

Comment: then the problem is with your json what about puting them like {["backwards":false,"idFrom":-1]}

Comment: still the same :/. Even checked the stream, but it's ok

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: look at the edit of the question. Since I am passing `String[].class` I realized that I shouldn't be passing an object, but an array instead.

Comment: you mean you chained it to [false, -1] and not the reverse as you mention in your edit . . .